# Binding detached issue when using a ControlTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a listbox which shows some labels
and then multiple (theoretically n, practically up to 6) listboxes which each show some values. Each of those n listboxes is its own view/viewmodel.

Now im changing a Property "HasChanged" in my Value-class inside the list box-ViewModel. I have a binding from "HasChanged" to "IsSelected". There is a List of instances of the value-class in each ViewModel.

Additionally, I have a trigger that listens to "IsSelected"-changes.
Part of the trigger is to apply a new control template.
Inside that Template, I define some styling to make the state visible to the user.

Now here is the problem:
I am using "ValidatesOnExceptions", to make the invalidity of values visible to the user.
Here is the code of the value property:

```
    public string Content
    {
        get
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modifiedValue))
                return modifiedValue;
            return content;
        }
        set
        {
            modifiedValue = value;
            HasChanged = (modifiedValue != content);
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(interpretAs))
                Validate();
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Content));
        }
    }
```

Since I'm setting the "HasChanged"-property thus triggering the selection-control template application, the control template sets a new TextBox with a border.

Now when I'm doing the validation, since the textbox-control has been changed, the binding is detached.
I get the following message:

[image: the error message]

Note: the problem only occurs when altering IsChanged and Validating with an error in the same setter-call.

I have noticed I could maybe do a workaround, using lots of style triggers instead of the control template. But there's still hope.. im also running into focus issues again when I cant use the control template.

This is the XAML of my Grid.Resources:

```
            <ControlTemplate x:Key="SelectedTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Border BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="LightBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Margin}" >
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" Margin="0" Padding="0" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent" Initialized="TextBox_Initialized" ToolTip="{Binding InterpretAs}" ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0"/>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, Path=HasChanged}"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiTrigger>
                    <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="True" />
                    </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" />
                    <!--<Setter Property="Border.BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
                    <Setter Property="Border.BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.Background" Value="Green"/>
                    <Setter Property="TextBox.HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>-->
                </MultiTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxDataTemplate">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" Padding="0" Background="Transparent" ToolTip="{Binding InterpretAs}" ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0" />
        </DataTemplate>
```

And this is the XAML for one of the listboxes:

```
        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Scroll:ScrollSynchronizer.HorizontalScrollGroup="H0" Scroll:ScrollSynchronizer.VerticalScrollGroup="V0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden">
        <ListBox Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" ItemsSource="{Binding PlatformValues}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ListBoxDataTemplate}" PreviewMouseWheel="ListBox_PreviewMouseWheel" SelectionMode="Extended" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" FocusManager.IsFocusScope="True">
            <ListBox.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding PlatformValues.Count, FallbackValue=0, TargetNullValue=0}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.Style>
        </ListBox>
    </ScrollViewer>
```

I have created a sample.

Try clicking a textbox then removing the last character. So far so good. Now try to set it to a string starting with "x" to trigger validation error, on the same textbox thats already been changed, there will be a red border indicating validation error, thats the desired behavior.

Now set a yet unchanged TextBox directly to "x", the desribed problem will be reproduced. Path to the sample project : LINK REMOVED - SEE ANSWER

Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you should read [how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It is hard to help if the issue is not easily reproducible

Comment: note: you need to trigger the validation error on not-yet edited textbox to produce the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to use a DataTemplate trigger instead of a ControlTemplate
In the DataTemplate I added a border with default background transparent.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ListBoxDataTemplate">
            <Border x:Name="ContentTextBoxBorder" BorderThickness="0" BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="-3 0">
                <TextBox x:Name="ContentTextBox" Text="{Binding Content, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" BorderThickness="0" Margin="0" Padding="0" Background="Transparent" ToolTip="{Binding InterpretAs}" ToolTipService.InitialShowDelay="0" />
            </Border>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                            Mode=FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListBoxItem}},
                            Path=IsSelected}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="ContentTextBoxBorder" Property="Background" Value="LightGreen"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="ContentTextBoxBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Gray"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
```

I set it to the desired color when "IsSelected" changes for an item. Working flawlessly.

To @Il Vic - if you're unable to help, keep your comments.

Comment: I am happy you found a solution for your issue. About comments I suggest you to read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) the section "_When should I comment?_". Users can leave comments even if they are not able to help you.

Comment: k, i didnt know. ill personally keep not doing so :) good day